# How do you describe this particular way of sitting?

Tags: phrase-requests

In Japanese, there's this thing called 横座り (*yokozuwari*, lit. "side-sitting") that looks like this:

[image: yokozuwari]

Basically, you sit on your knees, but then partially swing your legs out to one side. Is there a concise way of describing this in English? A short phrase or a single word; either one would work.

Comment: I tried but could not find one. I immediately thought of the little mermaid, through: http://mermaidsofearth.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/Rodolfo-Puig3L.jpg

Comment: It is called 'side-sitting'...  ->  http://starfishtherapies.wordpress.com/2009/04/27/a-glossary-of-sitting/

Comment: @mplungjan, I suspect your association might be due to the fact that the Danish term for sitting like this is in fact _havfruestilling_.

Comment: Lol :) So we just need to translate that

Comment: This was a fantastic question. Thanks for asking it. I had *exactly* the same question. Thanks @senshin

Answer (score 2):

There is no single word to describe this in English - you have to use a phrase, such as:

*She is sitting on the floor with her knees bent and legs to one side.*

Answer (score 2):

Here's a reference, it's an actual stock photo (service used by, eg, ad agencies etc), and

https://www.shutterstock.com/image-photo/woman-sitting-her-legs-side-65983426

the phrase they use is just

"Woman sitting with her legs to the side".

Related. I direct you to "Duchess Slant" (very easy to google).

(I wonder if a Japanese native speaker would think of that as "yokozuwari but on a chair" !)

Finally, I thought of referring to this as "lyre style" - in "classical" images when a woman is playing a lyre, she's inevitably sitting like this!  I asked a couple of people if "sitting lyre style" made them think of that position, and yes it did :) So, you never know. It would be interesting to know if there are ay Japanese text references to "classical" paintings of nymphs, etc, playing lyres, and it is described as yokozuwari!

---

Coda:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Based on a Google Image search, plenty of results show up for the term "side-sit" and "side-sitting." They all seem to depict this position quite well. To me, "side-sit" appears to be the best way to describe this pose.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to the EL&U. Your answer could be improved by providing references. See [tour](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score -1):

The only word I have come across in relation to this mode of sitting is ***seiza*** in martial arts and of course the famous tea ceremonies.

Description of this well-know formal Japanese sitting position can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seiza)

I suppose the shortest description for the sitting position you describe would be a *seiza with feet splayed to the left (/right)*.

Comment: _Seiza_ [seems to refer](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+seiza&um=1&ie=UTF-8&hl=en&tbm=isch&source=og&sa=N&tab=wi&ei=9zg_UpfNI-vZ0QW23oDICA#hl=en&q=+seiza&tbm=isch&um=1) to _upright_ kneeling.